# Combine two lists of dictionaries by value of key in dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists whose elements are dictionaries.

```
list1 = [
    {'id': 1, 'color': 'purple', 'size': 10},
    {'id': 2, 'color': 'red', 'size': 25},
    {'id': 3, 'color': 'orange', 'size': 1},
    {'id': 4, 'color': 'black', 'size': 100},
    {'id': 5, 'color': 'green', 'size': 33}
]

list2 = [
    {'id': 2, 'width': 22, 'age': 22.3},
    {'id': 5, 'width': 9, 'age': 1.7}
]
```

I want a third list that is the same length as the larger list, and where there is a dictionary element in the smaller list that has an id that matches a dictionary element in the larger list, merge the two dictionaries, so that the final output would look like:

```
list3 = [
    {'id': 1, 'color': 'purple', 'size': 10},
    {'id': 2, 'color': 'red', 'size': 25, 'width': 22, 'age': 22.3},
    {'id': 3, 'color': 'orange', 'size': 1},
    {'id': 4, 'color': 'black', 'size': 100},
    {'id': 5, 'color': 'green', 'size': 33, 'width': 9, 'age': 1.7}
]
```

Ideally if this could be done without looping over both lists, that would be ideal.

Comment: You're going to have to loop over the lists one way or the other. That's a consequence of having them in a list rather than a dictionary keyed to `id`.

Comment: I agree with @MarkMeyer. If you really cant iterate through it, you would need to convert each list to a full on dictionary, then merge them together by their key. Unless you are using numpy, you can prob us numpy groups between these two datasets

Answer (score 3):

Try this nested list comprehension with a `dict`ionary with unpacking, and a `next`, as well as another list comprehension:

```
list3 = [{**i, **next(iter([x for x in list2 if x['id'] == i['id']]), {})} for i in list1]
```

And now:

```
print(list3)
```

Is:

```
[{'id': 1, 'color': 'purple', 'size': 10}, {'id': 2, 'color': 'red', 'size': 25, 'width': 22, 'age': 22.3}, {'id': 3, 'color': 'orange', 'size': 1}, {'id': 4, 'color': 'black', 'size': 100}, {'id': 5, 'color': 'green', 'size': 33, 'width': 9, 'age': 1.7}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [
    {'id': 1, 'color': 'purple', 'size': 10},
    {'id': 2, 'color': 'red', 'size': 25},
    {'id': 3, 'color': 'orange', 'size': 1},
    {'id': 4, 'color': 'black', 'size': 100},
    {'id': 5, 'color': 'green', 'size': 33}
]

list2 = [
    {'id': 2, 'width': 22, 'age': 22.3},
    {'id': 5, 'width': 9, 'age': 1.7}
]

dict1 = defaultdict(dict)

for l in (list1, list2):
    for elem in l:
        dict1[elem['id']].update(elem)
list3 = dict1.values()

print(list(list3))
```

**O/P:**

```
[
  {
    'id': 1,'color': 'purple','size': 10
  },
  {
    'id': 2,'color': 'red','size': 25,'width': 22,'age': 22.3
  },
  {
    'id': 3,'color': 'orange','size': 1
  },
  {
    'id': 4,'color': 'black','size': 100
  },
  {
    'id': 5, 'color': 'green','size': 33, 'width': 9,'age': 1.7
  }
]
```

> list3 is not guaranteed to be sorted (.values() returns items in no
>   specific order, you can try this to sort.

```
from operator import itemgetter
...
new_list = sorted(dict1.values(), key=itemgetter("id"))
```